# NameError: name 'i' is not defined - Why does this happen?

Tags: python

I am making a rather simple wordle clone for my class. It functions exactly the same as wordle, just in a CLI. However, I am getting a weird error when testing.

When executed, python returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 46, in <module>
File "<string>", line 19, in input_guess
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

The code is

```
def input_guess():
    #gets input
    while True:
        guess = (str(input(f"Attempt {i + 1} >>> " ))).lower()
        if len(guess) != 5 or guess == int:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
        else:
            return guess.lower()

def split(word):
    #splits word
    return list(word)

while attempts < 6:
   # wordle
    guess = split(input_guess())
    for i in guess:
        if guess[i] == word[i]: #green
            response[i] = guess[i]
        if guess[i] in word and guess[i] != word[i]: # yellow
            response[i] = "-"
        if guess[i] not in word: #miss
            response[i] = "_"
```

Why am I getting this error?  What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Cheers

Comment: As the error says, you are not defining (telling Python) what `i` is.

Comment: `i` is only set in your outer scope, not in `input_guess`. If you want it to be available in the function, you need to pass it into that function as an argument.

Comment: Also, the `i` in your outer scope is a letter, but what you expect to have be `i` in your function is a number, so they're not the same kind of thing / it doesn't make sense to pass it at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's not even in the outer scope when `input_guess` is called. It is (would be) defined only after that function call.

Comment: I'm guessing the thing you want to pass into the function is `attempts`, not `i`. And btw -- where are you incrementing it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That makes sense! And I'm incrementing it just a few lines down, but I'm scared of collegeboard's incredibly holistic  plagiarism policies haha

Comment: Re: avoiding plagarism -- note that a [mre] can be any other program that causes the same problem in the same way, as long as showing you how to fix that other program would let you fix your real one; you don't need to provide your own code here -- you can write a new program that demonstrates the same issue. (Often, we _insist_ that people do that, when their program has too much content that doesn't relate to the question and so doesn't meet the "minimal" requirement; the trick is to make sure it still produces the problem the same way when run and hits the "reproducible" one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is being read logically, top to bottom. You don't define 'i' until your 'for' loop inside your 'while'. If you want 'i' to be accessible by input_guess, you need to either define it in a line before the function is defined or pass it in as a parameter into the function call, like
`guess = split(input_guess(i))`

Comment: That's not quite correct. You have to define it before the function is called, not before the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `i` is defined outside the function rather than inside it, then the function cannot access this variable. Solution: Either you pass the variable to the function as an argument when you call it, or you use a global variable. I, personally, would suggest the former, because I'm not very fond of using global variables (it's easier to mess up things with them), but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Of course you can access a variable from an outer scope in a function. Depending on what you do with it it's bad style, but it works.